# system restore status check

Tags: c#, console-application

Is there any way in C# console application to check whether the system restore is enabled or not.
I am able to create and end restore point but looking for way to check if it is enabled or disabled?

Comment: Google "create restore point programmatically".  Third hit looks good.

Comment: @HansPassant i coded 4 d creation already.i am looking for a hint on status check of system restore in C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check this reg key, hope this helps!

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SystemRestore
```

For XP - `DisableSR: 0 = enabled, 1 = disabled`

For Windows 7 - `RPSessionInterval: 0 = disabled, 1 = enabled`

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do the same thing today and ran across your post. It is simplistic but this is what worked for me.

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine;
RegistryKey rk1 = rk.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SystemRestore");
string sysRestore = rk1.GetValue("RPSessionInterval").ToString();
if (sysRestore.Contains("1"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("System Restore is Enabled");
}

if (sysRestore.Contains("0"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("System Restore is Disabled");
}
```